# Java EJB migration to Spring

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, migration, ejb

I'm migrating my **EJBs** to **Spring** beans and i have an issue with concurrency
on some beans i have annotation `@Lock(LockType.READ)` or `@Lock(LockType.WRITE)` on methods and class when concurrency was managed by container, but in **Spring** concurrency is managed by bean, what equivalent i could do in Spring regarding for locking two simultaneous read/write actions ?

For example on this class :

```
@Singleton
@Lock(READ)
public class SharedSingletonBean {
  private String data;
  private String status;

  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  @Lock(WRITE)
  public void setStatus(String newStatus) {
    status = newStatus;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `@Lock(READ)`,  you have nothing to do as the `READ` value means that the method does only reading and that it can be concurrently accessed, or shared, with several clients.

It is the case for example for these two methods :

```
public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

For `@Lock(WRITE)` as this one :

```
@Lock(WRITE)
public void setStatus(String newStatus) {
    status = newStatus;
}
```

it means that the method does writing.
So actually, the `WRITE` value makes the container to prevent any client to invoke the method if another client executing it.
To do the same thing with Spring, using the `volatile` modifier for the `String` field could be enough as you do only an assignment in the method.
You would not have  concurrency or no updated value issue as an assignment for a `volatile` variable is always atomic and updated for other threads and with this solution, as in your actual case, the last one client is always right.
Also, as a side note, I am not very convinced of the correct use of `@Lock READ` and `WRITE` here.

If you have more statements and that this could not be invoked atomically and in a transparent way for other clients, you could use a `synchronized` statement  on the current object :

```
 public void setStatus(String newStatus) {
    synchronize(this){
       myStatement();
       myOtherStatement();
       status = newStatus;
    }
  }
```